# Xcode 5.1 - Running app on iPad always installs in sandbox/debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

I have an iPhone app I've developed which I want to install on my iPad.  I connect up my iPad, run the app in Xcode in 'Release' mode and the app installs and runs.  However the app installs in 'sandbox/debug' mode.  I know this because the app uses APNS for push messages and when I attempt to send a message to the iPad (using the 'Production' APNS server) it is always rejected with 'Invalid token'.  Also once the app is installed it appears in the 'Applications' section in Organiser (development apps).  When I run the app on my iPhone and on another iPad everything works fine, messages are delivered and the app doesn't appear in Organiser.  I'm assuming this is a provisioning profile issue, but I've deleted all profiles off the iPad and re-setup, and even done a full 'Erase All Content and Settings' but it has made no difference.  Any ideas what the issue is with this specific device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the 'Production' version of the app running on my iPad by changing the 'Provisioning Profile' section within 'Code Signing' in the Build Settings of my Xcode project target.  Had to set it to the specific 'Ad Hoc' distribution profile for my app.  Still don't know why the problem was only occurring on 1 of my 3 iOS devices.